# What to do with comments to a question that are not helpful to anyone

Tags: discussion, comments

I was working on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200049/java-logging-to-file-only-first-message-is-written and the commenter is saying that he wants a full class, but at the same time minimal code.  It then turns into a comment "battle" which is not helpful to anyone.  What is the best way to go about such a situation.  Should the comments just be ignored?

Also, is what is being said actually correct and I am not putting in enough code to make it "complete" or should I put the extra brackets in to make it a class? Or is it minimal yet enough to help the users help me?

Comment: You have to add enough code (and only what is needed) so that people can reproduce your problem (appearantly it is not reproducible right now). Since it seems to work with other people it means that your problem is located elsewhere outside of the code shown. If this is the case then we can just keep guessing at any possible reason for your problem which is why it'll be put on hold until you add *all* **relevant** information for us to determine what's wrong. I agree that you might not always know what is relevant and what not, but that's part of the debugging process.

Comment: yeah, keep in mind that when I originally posted this question, is was not made clear that the reason why more code was being requested was because of nothing being wrong with the example.  Lesson learned, moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let that *discussion* sit there a while until it is resolved or nobody cares anymore. Then you would summarize anything useful from the comments as an additional comment or add this information to the post itself.

You then flag only one of the comments for moderator attention (*other*) and describe that it was resolved/discussion is not constructive and that the complete discussion should be removed.

<sup>Don't flag every one of the comments as *not constructive*, because it will be slightly more work for a mod and might be declined, because the mod might think that the information is still useful.</sup>

*OR (based on comments)*

Flag the first comment to be deleted with *other* describing the situation and then flag the other comments which need to be deleted as *not constructive* or *obsolete* or *too chatty* (whichever applies best to the individual comment).

Comment: Actually I find it easier if each individual comment is flagged. Then I can just click the "delete" link from the flag queue. Otherwise I have to go to the question/answer and look through *all* the comments deciding for myself which ones can be deleted and which ones need to remain. Other moderators might disagree.

Comment: But then you would have to read the comments more carefully and decide on a case by case basis. So you might not delete all comments and the review might be divided into multiple mods which would go to the post concurrently to see whats going on. I always wanted to know how the flag queue looks. Is there a screenshot around somewhere?

Comment: I can't show you a screenshot, but if a comment is flagged you see both the comment and the text of the flag so it's fairly quick and easy to decide whether the flag is appropriate or not. If multiple comments on the same post are flagged you see them all together so it's easy to either deal with them all from the queue or go to the post to do a little more digging.

Comment: Also make sure you flag appropriately. If the comment no longer applies use the *obsolete* flag rather than the *not constructive* or *too chatty* ones. It makes it so much easier to decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always flag the comments:

- rude or offensive
- not constructive
- obsolete
- too chatty
- other…

I guess "not constructive" would be the appropriate flag for this battle.

Comment: what would you say about the code provided, is it enough?

Comment: @Greg Nope, please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Might only need <10 more lines boilerplate, but that's for you to provide.)